# Put in Hazelcast Multimap lasts > 5sec on 2 node cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, multimap, hazelcast

i discovered a strange performance leak in one statement of our application, which runs on a two node cluster currently. It is this very method:

```
private void addIdToMember( final long id, final Member executedMember )
{
    this.entityIdToMemberHostname.put( id, executedMember.getInetSocketAddress( ).getHostName( ) );
}
```

The entityIdToMemberHostname map is initialized (once) as follows:

```
this.entityIdToMemberHostname = Hazelcast.getMultiMap( "entityIdToMemberHostname" );
```

Uncommenting the call to the addIdToMember method descreases the execution time of the surrounding method 5 seconds (it now takes only 20ms at all).

Is a put to a Hazelcast multimap that expensive in a cluster?

Comment: what is the maximum number of hostnames per id?

Comment: even 5 ms. is too much for a multimap.put() operation so something else is surely wrong. try to time the multimap.put() operation alone: String hostname = executedMember.getInetSocketAddress().getHostName();           long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); multimap.put(id, hostname); System.out.println("It took " + System.currentTimeMillis() - start);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was not to get the hostname but the IP to identify the member; hostname resolution was the problem.